# Does Time Machine make a backup of Windows if using Boot Camp?

Tags: bootcamp, time-machine, windows

I'm using Windows 7 on my Mac. On the Lion OS I installed Time Machine to keep a backup of my Laptop. Does this backup also cover the Windows partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Time Machine does not do this. The only reliable way to back up your BootCamp partition is to boot into Windows and run Windows-compatible disk backup software from within Windows, to back up to a separate external hard drive formatted with NTFS.

Winclone has not been updated in a long time and is not a useful solution.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it won't.

Check out **[Winclone](http://www.tuaw.com/2007/12/22/winclone-backup-your-boot-camp-partition/)**.